# Varchar date in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, where-clause

I have a varchar column called date_submitted and it's formatted like so:

03-06-2014 4:32 pm

02-14-2014 2:44 am

And so on...

I was wondering how I would get all of the dates from a certain date or from something like 20 days ago. This select statement is something along the lines of what I need.

```
SELECT date_submitted FROM myTable WHERE date_submitted < 02-14-2014 12:00 am
```

Comment: Format your dates correctly when you insert them into your database.

Comment: No kidding. If the person who made this database was still working here I would have strangled him myself...

Comment: Well, they're not there now so fix it. Then perform your query. CREATE TABLE my_new_table AS SELECT STR_TO_DATE(my_bad_date_column,'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p') x FROM my_table;

Comment: Great point, I'll ask the boss for the go ahead. Way to make the world a better place, one database at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this with `DATE_SUB`

```
  SELECT date_submitted 
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_submitted, '%m-%d-%Y') > DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT((NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y'), INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

Comment: Love date_sub, forgot all about it. Thank you SQL professionals for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [CONVERT](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) your datetime column appropriately like this:

```
SELECT date_submitted FROM myTable 
WHERE convert(datetime,date_submitted,100) < DATE_SUB(convert(datetime,'02-14-2014 12:00 am',100), INTERVAL 20 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, or else you'll be comparing a string to a date, you won;t get good results

```
SELECT date_submitted 
FROM myTable 
WHERE 
date_format(str_to_date(date_submitted,'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i %p'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 DAY);
```